# how to interpret the two-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, two-way

I have a data set like below, and I would like to answer the question "whether the mean of v1-v4 by income group differ from each other?"

```
      income    v1    v2     v3    v4
   1      q1 44.33 13.63 121.22  2.32
   2      q2 56.71 16.32  114.3  2.22
   3      q3 46.81 19.09 113.99  6.58
   4      q4 59.06 13.08 173.27  6.08
   5      q5 43.25 11.68 148.41 17.44
   6      q1 48.03 11.68 137.95  2.04
   7      q2 58.34 15.12 112.76 10.79
   8      q3 52.09 12.09 157.99  2.92
   9      q4 40.64 15.04 152.32  0.09
   10     q5 41.61 17.93 174.08  10.8
   11     q1 50.27  11.7 102.98 10.11
   12     q2 51.02  10.4 150.79 12.03
   ...
```

So i generate a mean table as below

```
      income variable    value
   1      q1       v1  52.1625
   2      q2       v1  50.3025
   3      q3       v1  53.0775
   4      q4       v1  45.9775
   5      q5       v1  49.0875
   6      q1       v2  15.2550
   7      q2       v2  13.1050
   8      q3       v2  16.0525
   9      q4       v2  16.3825
   10     q5       v2  16.8250
   11     q1       v3 182.6650
   12     q2       v3 149.5175
   ...
```

and then produce the ANOVA with the below script, and got the results

```
aov <- aov(value~variable + income,data=mean)
summary(aov)


            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
variable     3  74780   24927 286.225  2e-11 ***
income       4    403     101   1.156  0.378    
Residuals   12   1045      87                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My question is how should I interpret the p-value.

Since my original question is "does the mean of "v" differ by income group?", does the p=2e-11 imply that the mean does differ by income group in at least one of the "v"?

Then what does the p=0.378 tell me? or should I look at this p-value instead?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A p-value of 2e-11 in this model tells you that you have very strong evidence that at least one of the 'variable' groups is different from the others in terms of 'value'. The test does not tell you anything about the relationship between income group and 'variable'.

The p-value of 0.378 for income tells you that there is no statistically significant difference in terms of 'value' between the income groups.

If you want to understand the relationship between both income and 'variable' in terms of 'value' you could include an interaction term using:

`aov <- aov(value ~ variable * income, data = mean)
summary(aov)`

The p-value for the interaction will tell you whether or not the effect of a given  variable/income level depends on the level of the other (i.e. whether their effect is additive or multiplicative).

If you want to determine whether variable is influenced by income group then you need a different test all together - probably something like a proportional log-odds model.

Let me know if anything is unclear!